# Is there a best practice to reboot a cluster

Tags: kubeadm

I followed Alex Ellis' excellent [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/alexellis/fdbc90de7691a1b9edb545c17da2d975) that uses `kubeadm` to spin-up a K8s cluster on Raspberry Pis. It's unclear to me what the best practice is when I wish to power-cycle the Pis.

I suspect `sudo systemctl reboot` is going to result in problems. I'd prefer not to delete and recreate the cluster each time starting with `kubeadm reset`.

Is there a way that I can shutdown and restart the machines without deleting the cluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite old but I imagine others may eventually stumble upon it so I thought I would provide a quick answer because there is, in fact, a best practice around this operation.

The first thing that you're going to want to ensure is that you have a [highly available cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/). This consists of at least 3 masters and 3 worker nodes. Why 3? This is so that at any given time they can always form a quorum for eventual consistency.

Now that you have an HA Kubernetes cluster, you're going to have to go through every single one of your application manifests and ensure that you have specified Resource Requests and Limitations. This is so that you can ensure that a pod will never be scheduled on a pod without the required resources. Furthermore, in the event that a pod has a bug that causes it to consume a highly abnormal amount of resources, the limitation will prevent it from taking down your cluster.

Now that that is out of the way, you can begin the process of rebooting the cluster. The first thing you're going to do is reboot your masters. So run `kubectl drain $MASTER` against one of your (at least) three masters. The API Server will now reject any scheduling attempts and immediately start the process of evicting any scheduled pods and migrating their workloads to your other masters.

Use `kubectl describe node $MASTER` to monitor the node until all pods have been removed. Now you can safely connect to it and reboot it. Once it has come back up, you can now run `kubectl uncordon $MASTER` and the API Server will once again begin scheduling Pods to it. Once again use `kubectl describe $NODE` until you have confirmed that all pods are READY.

Repeat this process for all of the masters. After the masters have been rebooted, you can safely repeat this process for all three (or more) worker nodes. If you properly perform this operation you can ensure that all of your applications will maintain 100% availability provided they are using multiple pods per service and have proper [Deployment Strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy) configured.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. My challenge had been that I had 3 Pis with a single master and a desire to periodically power all the machines down. The cluster didn't reboot when I did. Your answer is a good and helpful answer. Thanks.