# Restarting master and losting pods on nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I setup my cluster with one master and two nodes. I can create pods on nodes. If my master node fails (reboot) when I use kubeadm reset and then kubeadm init I lost all my pods, deployments, services.

Am I losting my pods because reset? What should I do?

Some similar questions:

https://stackpointcloud.com/community/question/how-do-i-restart-my-kubernetes-cluster

[Is there a best practice to reboot a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362855/is-there-a-best-practice-to-reboot-a-cluster)

Comment: Did you found a best practice to reboot your k8s cluster? I have the same problem, my k8s cluster on an vserver is completly crashed (all pods/containers are exited because of OOM after 4 Months running). My biggest concern is, to delete the whole configuration. From the answer of @janos lenart i would try to restart my OS system first. Any other suggestions? I'm using K8s 1.16 & Istio 1.3.0.

Comment: Restarting the vserver doesnt solved the problem. The api-server etc wasnt started. Its still all dead.

Comment: Got the solution: Setting fail-swap-on to false:
`vi /etc/sysconfig/kubelet` (on CentOS 7) and insert following line: `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false`. systemd starts kubelet automatically or you can do it manually (see here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53333#issuecomment-333587943 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubeadm reset` on the master deletes all configuration (files and a database too). There is no way back.

You should not run `kubeadm init` when you reboot the master. `kubeadm init` is a one off action to bootstrap the cluster. When the master is rebooted your OS's init system (systemd, upstart, ...) should start `kubelet` which in turn starts the master components (as containers). An exception is if your cluster is [self-hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-alpha/#cmd-phase-self-hosting)

Comment: On previous versions kubeadm doesn't delete all configuration made on cluster. I'm using v.1.10 (newest). How can I setup my cluster in order to reboot and not losting all configuration? If I use kubeadm init I need to do kubeadm reset first.